# python get origin information of windows files

Tags: python, windows, properties

I created a file in 2020, saved the content in 2021 and I copied the file in 2022. In windows, the creating time will be 2022 instead of 2020. However, in windows it does exist content creating time in the part of origin of details. I'd like to extract the original creating time (2020) of the file, but failed with python function os.path.getctime. Is there other ways to have a tried? thanks.

Comment: I can the the original creating date and the date of last save by right click -> property -> details. However, I failed to extract these information by python. Thank you any way.